# Mask Shape is () trying to load image and mask

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

Hi guys i am trying to load Image and mask but i am getting mask shape as ()
my name change is perfect as it should be 224,224,3 . I am using rgb to train and binary as mask (breakhis breast cancer dataset)

here is the code to load data

```
train_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/breakhis_classification/train'
train_image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
train_generator = train_image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=seed)
```

Now my folder structure is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnnqm.png , I am not sure where the problem is

I try to print it before using plt to show it

It gave me this

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

I am assuming they are class label instead of mask if I am not wrong